# Lightning components in Salesforce Community

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components, community-builder

I added `implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes"` to the component bundle and then I added it to the community home page in the community builder.

1. After logging to the Community when I refresh the browser I get - url no longer exists error.
2. when I click on the community url - it takes me to the home page instead of login page. how do I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you post your component with controller, are you sure you are logging in as a community user?

Comment: Yes sure I was logging in as community user. for which question you are asking me to post the component and controller?

Comment: Your question says "Lightning component" I wanted to see what is in the component and the client side controller to see what url you might be referencing

Comment: sorry I will not be able to paste the code.. :(